# How to tell if my process's user token the same as the token for logon session that it runs under?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process, winlogon

How to tell from within my interactive GUI process that its `user token` is the same as the user token for `logon session` that the process is running under?

PS. I cannot assume that my process is running elevated.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: To not put process's link into the `HKCU` autorun key if it's not running in the logon session.

Comment: This is starting to sound like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) ("*asking about your attempted **solution** rather than your actual **problem**"*). What are you really trying to accomplish in the first place?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: "_How to tell if my process's user token the same as the token for logon session that it runs under?_"

Comment: Checking the user token is what you *think* you need to do in order to solve your original problem, but what is the actual problem you are trying to solve that lead you to believe checking the user token was the solution? What are you actually doing that is so user-sensitive that it can't be done through other means? You are asking for help to make a chosen solution work, when you should be asking what the correct way is to solve the original problem. That is the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) I am referring to.

Comment: I think you mean the Remote Desktop session, not the logon session?  (Authentication tokens are tied to the associated logon session so there wouldn't be anything to check.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: No, I mean what i wrote above. A RD session is a logon session too. So it's included.

Comment: Each logged-on Remote Desktop session is associated with a particular logon session, but they're not the same thing.  All of the tokens associated with any particular logon session should always have the same user account so I don't think the question makes sense as written.  (When you use runas, for example, the new process runs in the same RD session but a new logon session.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: To see how this can apply, create a standard Windows user account, log in as that user, and run a process as administrator. In this case the user token (admin) will have a different SID than the interactive logon session (standard user) that the process runs in. From there on, you can shift-right-click the process image file and pick any user in "Run as different user" menu option.

Comment: OK, you're talking about the Remote Desktop session.  That was obvious, really, so I probably shouldn't have made a fuss, but I think it important to be aware that the Windows kernel gives "logon session" a specific (and different!) technical meaning.  When you run a process as administrator as you describe the kernel creates a new logon session to run it in - it does *not* run in the standard user's logon session.  (That's why you don't see the standard user's mapped network drives.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: No, I'm not talking about RD session :)

Comment: For reference, if you call [GetTokenInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379626(v=vs.85).aspx) the `TokenSessionId` option gives you the Remote Desktop session.  The `TokenOrigin` option gives you the logon session ID.

Comment: The code in your answer says otherwise. :-)  ProcessIdToSessionId and the WTS functions all manipulate "Remote Desktop Services sessions" or RD sessions for short.  Granted, the terminology is awkward.  That's because in older versions of Windows there were only multiple RD sessions if you were actually using Remote Desktop.  Then they found out that RD sessions were incredibly useful, so now even interactive logons use them.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Oh, OK. I see your point. Yes, there's one way Microsoft can come up with a very confusing terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Cutting through [demagoguery](http://xyproblem.info/) I think I got it.

It's somewhat of a hack, as I can't seem to find a way to retrieve logon user token from a session ID to compare it's `SID` to the user token `SID` from my process. The only API that I know of that can do this ([WTSQueryUserToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383840(v=vs.85).aspx)) requires `SE_TCB_NAME` privilege which my "little process" will most certainly not have.

So assuming that no two user accounts can have the same name on the same domain (or workgroup), this seems to do the trick so far:

```
#define SIZEOF(f) (sizeof(f) / sizeof(f[0]))

int IsRunningInOwnLogonUserSession()
{
    //Checks if our process is running in its own logon user session
    //RETURN:
    //      = 1 if yes
    //      = 0 if no
    //      = -1 if error determining -- check GetLastError() for info
    int nOSError = NO_ERROR;
    int res = -1;

    DWORD dwProcSessID = -1;
    if(::ProcessIdToSessionId(::GetCurrentProcessId(), &dwProcSessID))
    {
        TCHAR buffProcUsrName[UNLEN + 1];
        buffProcUsrName[0] = 0;

        DWORD dwcbSz = 0;
        LPTSTR pStrUsrName = NULL;
        if(WTSQuerySessionInformation(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, dwProcSessID, WTSUserName, &pStrUsrName, &dwcbSz) &&
            pStrUsrName &&
            pStrUsrName[0])
        {
            LPTSTR pStrDomName = NULL;
            if(WTSQuerySessionInformation(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, dwProcSessID, WTSDomainName, &pStrDomName, &dwcbSz) &&
                pStrDomName &&
                pStrDomName[0])
            {
                dwcbSz = SIZEOF(buffProcUsrName);
                ::GetUserName(buffProcUsrName, &dwcbSz);
                buffProcUsrName[SIZEOF(buffProcUsrName) - 1] = 0;

                if(buffProcUsrName[0])
                {
                    //The domain name is somewhat tricky as I don't know
                    //what format 'WTSDomainName' supplied it in...
                    //I'm assuming old, generic NetBIOS...
                    TCHAR buffProcDomName[MAX_PATH];
                    buffProcDomName[0] = 0;
                    GetEnvironmentVariable(_T("USERDOMAIN"), buffProcDomName, SIZEOF(buffProcDomName));
                    buffProcDomName[SIZEOF(buffProcDomName) - 1] = 0;

                    if(buffProcDomName[0])
                    {
                        //Compare the two
                        if(lstrcmpi(pStrUsrName, buffProcUsrName) == 0 &&
                            lstrcmpi(pStrDomName, buffProcDomName) == 0)
                        {
                            //Same
                            res = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Different
                            res = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        nOSError = ::GetLastError();
                }
                else
                    nOSError = ::GetLastError();
            }
            else
                nOSError = ::GetLastError();

            if(pStrDomName)
            {
                WTSFreeMemory(pStrDomName);
                pStrDomName = NULL;
            }
        }
        else
            nOSError = ::GetLastError();

        if(pStrUsrName)
        {
            WTSFreeMemory(pStrUsrName);
            pStrUsrName = NULL;
        }
    }
    else
        nOSError = ::GetLastError();

    ::SetLastError(nOSError);
    return res;
}
```

If someone finds a better solution, let me know...

Comment: I would hazard a guess that the format of the domain name depends on how the user logged on.  Perhaps converting the username and domain from WTSQuerySessionInformation to a SID using LookupAccountName (and then comparing it to the SID in your user token) would be more robust?  Another option you might try is to use WTSQuerySessionInformation to get WTSUserConfigTerminalServerProfilePath and seeing whether it is your user profile directory or not.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Hmm. What do you mean by "how the user logged on"?

Comment: As for your other suggestions, I'm not sure how I'd fit a user name into `LookupAccountName` without knowing the machine name. As for `WTSUserConfigTerminalServerProfilePath`, is it the actual API? In either case I hate syntactically comparing NT paths. It's a "hairball" of its own.

Comment: I mean the domain name might be in the format the user chose to enter it in, rather than in any fixed format.  (That *is* just a guess though.)  LookupAccountName shouldn't be a problem, use NULL for `lpSystemName` since the account you want is by definition valid on the local system, or else the user wouldn't have been able to log on.

Comment: Sorry, should have said [WTSQueryUserConfig](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383859) which has the option to check the profile path.  To check whether two paths match, you can use GetFileInformationByHandle or GetFileInformationByHandleEx to compare the file indexes.  But now that I look at the docs again there is a complication with Windows 8 and ReFS, so comparing the SIDs is probably simpler.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Thanks. Yes, `LookupAccountName` should do the job but doesn't it just complicate things. I mean it will look up account SID by user name and then I need to compare SIDs. Wouldn't it be easier just to compare names in the first place like I did? (I was hoping for SID comparison if I could obtain logon SID from logon session ID directly.)

Comment: Not *much* easier.  Both LookupAccountName and EqualSid function are straightforward enough.  The string comparison just seems unsafe, since there are several different possible formats the domain name might be in.  But the environment variable and the session information are presumably both set by the same code, so perhaps they're always going to be in the same format; I suppose you'll find out!  Of course the user could change the value of USERDOMAIN, but if they do that they deserve broken software. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: The reason I started using `USERDOMAIN` is because `GetComputerNameEx(ComputerNameDnsDomain)` was calling it internally.

Comment: Holy ... uh, cripes.  That's some surprisingly unsafe behaviour, even for Windows. :-)  Thanks, knowing that may come in useful one day.